# Converting "Pre-Zipped" list values to integers

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion, starmap

I frequently have a list of "pre-zipped" (elements are lists) data. I'm trying to convert each item to an integer (from an input string, usually).

How can I make each element in a complex list into an integer?

I initially attempted a list comprehension:

```
ls = ["1", "2", ["3", "4", "5"], "6"]
ls = [int(i) for i in ls]
```

But the int function can't take an iterable, so it breaks on int(["3", "4", "5"])

Looking around, I learned about the map() function, which applies a function to each item in an iterable.

```
ls = ["1", "2", ["3", "4", "5"], "6"]

print(map(lambda x: int(x), ls))
```

The above code outputs

```
<map object at 0x000001A84C46E898>
```

But when I attempt to convert that to a list, I get an error

```
ls = ["1", "2", ["3", "4", "5"], "6"]

print(list(map(lambda x: int(x), ls)))
```

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

So that sounds to me like map is passing the int() function the list. I also tried itertools.starmap():

```
import itertools

ls = ["1", "2", ["3", "4", "5"], "6"]

print(list(itertools.starmap(lambda x: int(x), ls)))
```

This, however, seems to behave the same as map(): returning a map object that can't be converted to a list.

Help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exeption handling on things that throw on `int(thing)`:

```
def makeInt(data):
    try:
        k = int(data)
    except ValueError:
        k = [makeInt(d) for d in data]
    return k

ls = ["1", "2", ["3", "4", "5"], "6"]

t = makeInt(ls)
print(t)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 6]
```

This will still fail if you supply non-integer data into your lists.